# Why my mask failed in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import numpy as np

names = np.array(['Bob', 'Joe', 'Will', 'Bob', 'Will', 'Joe', 'Joe'])
data = np.random.randn(7, 4) + 0.8

print (data)

mask2= ((names != 'Joe') == 7.0)
d2 = data[mask2]
print (d2)

d3 = data[names != 'Joe'] = 7.0
print (d3)
```

Actually,my intention was to get the same solution both with mask and with other expression. 
I have solved it with Patric,s help

```
mask2= (names != 'Joe')
data[mask2] = 7.0
print (data)
```

Then I have:

```
[[ 7.          7.          7.          7.        ]
 [-0.73168514  2.26996071 -0.24892468  1.31421193]
 [ 7.          7.          7.          7.        ]
 [ 7.          7.          7.          7.        ]
 [ 7.          7.          7.          7.        ]
 [ 0.74771766  2.44888399  0.62641731 -0.12963696]
 [ 0.08604169  2.25468039  2.1960925   0.88218726]]
```

Comment: What are you trying to do, what's your expected result, and what do you actually get?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `mask2 = names != 'Joe';data[mask2] = 7`?

Comment: Yes,@Padraic Cunningham,I meant that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> mask2 = ((names != 'Joe') == 7.0)
>
> Why my mask failed in Python?

This mask doesn't make sense, with that expression, you are compared the result of `names != 'Joe'` with `7.0`

```
In [13]: names != 'Joe'
Out[13]: array([ True, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

So it's natural that this will get you all `False` everywhere:

```
In [14]: ((names != 'Joe') == 7.0)
Out[14]: array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Your other mask makes sense, something in this form:

```
x[mask] = value
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand, but if you expect 7.0 in all rows except Joe's, maybe what you want is :

```
data[names != 'Joe'] = 7.0
print data
```